# Creating a flow that will on an existing account create an opportunity and populated some details

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

i have been working on this for the last 2 days and making bit of progress, i am stuck at the first part which is crutial to me and i cannot get my head around it yet, i think once i can understand it, i will be fine as it is the main part for things i want to do with flow,

i have added some screen to try aid in my simple attempt at a flow,

so i want to create a new opportunity on an existing account, then add some info to the new opp, i have go to the point where i can add add a button to the account which when i click it creates an opportunity with the info i want, but it doesnt link it back to the original account i created it from.

i feel i am close but missing something obvious, and i am starting to get very fed up with it haha :) but i am determined to master this art as no one else has used these in our team before and it can steer us away from totally customizing the system with lots of apex and visual force (which is not desired ) to achieve what i believe can be done with flows.

i have had some help in the last 2 days on here which has been great but was advised to repost with some pics to help show where i am at so i have :)

any help would be greatly appreciated guys :P

Thanks JR

[image: cap]
[image: cap]
[image: cap]
[image: cap]
[image: cap]
[image: cap]
[image: cap]

Comment: I have figured it out my button was setup wrong, it needed to be like the below, noobie mistake, a days stressing just came to an end 45 mins before i finish, i also had to change my variable to input only, it was private,

now to stress myself out with adding creating an event in the same flow also :) this wont end for a while haha

/flow/Creating_an_opportunity?varAccontID={!Account.Id}

Answer (score 0):

To this specific part of your question, "i want to create a new opportunity on an existing account, then add some info to the new opp, i have go to the point where i can add add a button to the account which when i click it creates an opportunity with the info i want, but it doesnt link it back to the original account i created it from.", yes you just need to add the retURL={!Account.Id} parameter to the URL that launches your flow.

Glad you figured out the other configuration issues that were holding you up!